# Remove unnecessary Characters by using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Do you know how to remove below kind of Characters at once on a query ?

**Note :** .I'm retrieving this data from the Access app and put only the valid data into the SQL.

```
select  DISTINCT ltrim(rtrim(a.Company)) from [Legacy].[dbo].[Attorney] as a
```

This column is `company name` column.I need to keep `string characters only`.But I need to remove `numbers only rows,numbers and characters rows,NULL,Empty and all other +,-`.

[image]

Comment: What is unwanted? `13401` is unwanted, but `1115` is wanted?

Comment: Define "below kind of character" Is there a pattern??

Comment: @Nicarus this column is `company name` column.It's fine to have number and character.But I need to remove numbers only.

Comment: You have been around here long enough to know this question lacks enough information to give you a solid answer. If you are trying to remove numbers only why should lines 2,3,4,5 & 7 be removed? Are we to continue guessing at your business logic or can you share it with us?

Comment: @SeanLange I have updated it.Please let me know what else do you need.Thanks.

Comment: Define what "all other +,-" means. You have to tell us what you want here. What about something like "#"? Or maybe "#$%^&*". And why are those valid or invalid?

Comment: Here is the problem. All of those are perfectly valid strings. Think about this for a second. I can't see your screen, I have no idea what your project is or what you are trying to do other than what you share in your post. At this point is so vague nobody could answer it. Anything I would suggest is a shot in the dark.

Comment: @Sampath - Its all strings isn't it. A string is a type, not a character.

Comment: Side note: this is a fantastic example of `garbage in garbage out` and why you should always validate input up front.

Comment: @Igor You can see this word `Legacy`.I'm retrieving data from Access app and put those data into the SQL.That data will be used by new SPA app.On that new app have all the input validations.

Comment: @Sampath - 1) maybe I should have written `a developer` instead of `you`, I did not mean you personally. 2) MS Access? How many records are you talking about here? It might be easier to dump it into Excel and send it back to the team responsible for the actual data and ask them to remove all the faulty data, then re-import and execute a couple of statements so you are left with the stuff they want to keep. With garbage data like this manual intervention is sometimes the easiest way.

Comment: @Igor Yes,My idea was also the same.But they refused to do so and asked me to remove as much as garbage data and later they will remove balance by through the new app's master data entering section.Now I don't have any other option.

Comment: @Sampath - again, how many records are there? IMO that's when a good developer either pushes back or passive aggressively pushes everything into the database anyway only omitting the data that can very easily be ignored. No sense in working very hard to create a crazy technical solution for something that can be done faster and better using a manual approach. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your extremely vague "rules" I am going to make a guess.

Maybe something like this will be somewhere close.

```
select DISTINCT ltrim(rtrim(a.Company)) 
from [Legacy].[dbo].[Attorney] as a 
where LEN(ltrim(rtrim(a.Company))) > 1
and IsNumeric(a.Company) = 0
```

This will exclude entries that are not at least 2 characters and can't be converted to a number.

Answer (score 0):

This should select the rows you want to delete:

```
where company not like '%[a-zA-Z]%' and -- has at least one vowel
      company like '%[^ a-zA-Z0-9.&]%'  -- has a not-allowed character
```

The list of allowed characters in the second expression may not be complete.

If this works, then you can easily adapt it for a `delete` statement.